# GraphQL client.executeItemQuery is throwing error

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, graphql, pca

Hi I am trying custom graphql call using dxa apis

i am calling this line

```
InputItemFilter inputItemFilter = new InputItemFilter();
inputItemFilter.setCustomMeta(customMetaCriteria);
InputSortParam inputSortParam = new InputSortParam();
inputSortParam.setSortBy(SortFieldType.LAST_PUBLISH_DATE);

ItemConnection itemConnection = getPcaClient().executeItemQuery(inputItemFilter,
                inputSortParam, new Pagination(), "",
                ContentIncludeMode.INCLUDE_DATA, false, null);
```

but i am getting error

```
"errorType": "ValidationError",             
"extensions": null,             
"message": "Variable 'inputSortParam' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'SortOrderType!'",            
"path": null,           
"suppressed": [],           
"localizedMessage": "Variable 'inputSortParam' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'SortOrderType!'"
```

or is there any method where i can only pass **filter** and get the respected output.

Could someone please advise what i am missing here.

Comment: added InputSortParam inputSortParam = new InputSortParam();
        inputSortParam.setOrder(SortOrderType.Ascending);
        inputSortParam.setSortBy(SortFieldType.ITEM_ID); this fixed the problem

Comment: Good to see you found the problem. Please consider answering your own question with the solution with some explanation of what was wrong. This can help others (and even yourself in the future) who have a similar issue in the future. You can choose to post as a community answer or accept your own answer, though it's good to give others a chance to answer as well, in case someone has a correct answer with additional context that you prefer over your own. :-)

Comment: sure @AlvinReyes, i'll add this as answer thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

added

```
InputSortParam inputSortParam = new InputSortParam();
inputSortParam.setOrder(SortOrderType.Ascending);
inputSortParam.setSortBy(SortFieldType.LAST_PUBLISH_DATE);
```

this fixed the problem. based on error i figured out both fields **order** and **sortBy** on are required InputSortParam.